# Ajuda cURL+ sleep

Tags: php, ajax, libcurl

Existe a possibilidade de fazer um script que tenho em CURL aguardar 50 segundos para executar?

Tentei sleep mais ele da stop para todo a execução, estou precisando pausar somente o Curl em questão

```
function writeMessage() {
$fields = array('site' => $site, 'uid' => $uid, 'ip' => $ip, 'id' => $id);
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://xxxx.xx/widget-ajax.php');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
    }
```

consigo fazer ele esperar 50 segundos ante de de executar sem trava o restante do código?

Tentei também por ajax em jsonp mais está complicado realiza o POST cross-domain a segurança do navegador impede..

Answer (score -1):

Partindo do princípio que você já conhece o fluxo de requisições ajax (pelo fato de ter tentando jsonp), você pode fazer um sistema de "proxy" onde você faria a requisição ajax para um arquivo específico no seu servidor e esse arquivo faria a requisição via curl ou file_get_contents para o site desejada para driblar o CORS. o fluxo seria mais ou menos assim.

1. Usuario entra na pagina abc
2. A página é rederizada no navegador
3. Após x segundos, um js na página abc faz ajax para o arquivo xpto.php no mesmo servidor.
4. Arquivo xpto.php faz cURL, prepara os dados para devolver para abc
5. página abc recebe os dados e faz a lógica do negócio

Na prática o fluxo implementado seria mais ou menos assim:

**Página abc** (somente a parte do ajax com jQuery)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.get('xpto.php', function (dados) {
            alert('Dados recebidos, veja o console para mais detalhes');
            console.log(dados);
            // fazer alguma coisa coms os dados
        });
    }, 50000); // 50 segundos
});
```

**Arquivo xpto.php**

```php
<?php
$fields = array('site' => $site, 'uid' => $uid, 'ip' => $ip, 'id' => $id);
$ch  = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://xxxx.xx/widget-ajax.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

// Talvez você precise desativar a verificação de peers localmente
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// To Do não esquecer de tratar a respota antes de devolvê-la
echo json_encode(['data' => $result]);
exit;
```

Se você precisar sempre ficar fazendo a checagem de tempos em tempos basta trocar a função de `setTimeout` para `setInterval`

Se você preferir um abordagem apenas do lado o PHP você tentar uma das soluções propostas neste [artigo](https://segment.com/blog/how-to-make-async-requests-in-php/) (em inglês)

Comment: Isso nao funciona, ele paraliza todo o script da pagina!

Comment: @ViníciusRemonti Editei minha resposta com um exemplo como uma alternativa ao jsonp que evita o problema do CORS

Answer (score -1):

Existe mas não é muito comum fazer isso em php. Como o código é executado assíncrono, tu vai ter que fazer um fork do processo e nele tu vai esperar 50s enquanto isso no processo principal vai ser executado o resto da sua lógica.

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
     die('erro');
} else if ($pid) {
    // continua o resto do processo aqui;
    pcntl_wait($status);
} else {
    sleep(50);
    writeMessage();
}
// Qualquer código que tiver aqui vai ser executado pelos dois processos
// então vai passar duas vezes por aqui, por isso deixar o resto da lógica dentro
// do if pra ser rodado somente no processo pai.
```

Recomendo ver melhor sobre fork [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php). Além disso se estiver utilizando php 7.2+ tu pode utilizar uma nova biblioteca padrão pra [paralelismo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.parallel.php).